# Can we add drupal.org username as a profile field?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This would enable a simple 1:1 mapping of Drupal.org accounts and Drupal Answers accounts, allowing for some cool integration projects down the road.

For example it would allow [Certifed to Rock](http://certifiedtorock.com/) to incorporate Drupal Answers reputation into their score calculation!

Comment: I would really like if this should be possible. Is it better a field for the Drupal.org username, or a field for the link to the Drupal.org user profile?

Comment: I suppose user-id (numeric) would be ideal

Comment: For reference: kiamlaluno also [asked us at the WordPress site](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/576/would-you-be-interested-in-having-a-user-profile-field-for-the-link-to-the-wordpr) whether we would like to join this request.

Answer (score 5):

If your goal is for Certified to Rock to take reputation from Drupal Answers into account, it might be better to pursue adding a Drupal Answers user ID to the user profiles on Drupal.org.

**Edit**: For reference, the [thread about adding twitter usernames](http://drupal.org/node/817324) to Drupal.org in the [Webmasters issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/webmasters).

**Edit**: [Link for created issue on Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1135722)

Comment: There's a chance Drupal Answers won't make it out of beta, so it might not be the right time to make such a request. If and when Drupal Answers launches, I'd say this is a good idea.

Comment: @Mark agreed! Take a look here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2978/drupal-answers i'd say there's a pretty solid chance! ;)

Answer (score 3):

It would be very unusual to add a custom, site-specific field to the user profile. The 'about me' field was set up for just this type of activity. Users are free to add any type of information there. They can add their drupal.org account name, a link to their profile, or any other information they find useful to this site.

Comment: I realize that, but the "problem" is that since so much information is available in the "About Me" field, its hard to extract this one piece of information. That said, I think having site-specific profile fields in general is a decent idea because people have profiles elsewhere and integrating (or at least identifying) them whenever possible is always an interesting idea!

Comment: @Alex: The [feature-request] has been issued. That is the best way to request that such a feature be added.

Comment: thanks a lot! Is there anywhere we can keep track of the progress?

Comment: @Alex: Right here in this thread. Not all [feature-requests] are implemented on the basis that they've been asked. It's a combination of the merits of the request, the voting, the resources available, and how the feature fits in with the vision for how this stuff works. Any updates to the feature request would be indicated here.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for getting this rolling! :)